# member of a structure pointer is also a pointer. what should temp->data represent.Question is more clear in code

Tags: c, structure

In first print   `temp->data` is address
whereas in later print `temp->data` becomes value
and `*temp->data` prints nothing

I have tried `assining` value like

```
int n = 5;
temp->data = &n;
```

then *temp->data prints value 5

```
structure is
struct Node{
    int *data;
    struct Node *next;
};
/***part of code ***/
struct Node *temp = NULL;
    temp = head;
    while(count != l){
         count++;
         printf("%x   %x  %x ",temp,temp->data,&(temp->data));
         printf("enter %d element\n",count);
            scanf("%d",&(temp->data));
             printf("%d\n",temp->data);
```

Comment: If you are asking why you declared the member as an `int*` instead of an `int`... you tell us. We have no idea what this code is supposed to do. It looks like a linked list. It is custom for linked list nodes to hardcopy the data into the node itself. Why you aren't doing that, is anyone's guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int *data;` creates an unintialized pointer and must point to valid memory before it can be used. (failure to do so leads to *Undefined Behavior*, and likely a SegFault)

For example:

```
temp->data = malloc (sizeof *temp->data);
if (temp->data == NULL) {
    perror ("malloc-temp->data");
    /* handle error, e.g. return/exit */
}
```

Now you can assign an integer value to `temp->data`. (don't forget to `free` the memory you allocate when it is no longer needed)

Presuming you have done that (in some other code you didn't post), the following is wrong:

```
 scanf("%d",&(temp->data));
```

`temp->data` is already a pointer, no `'&'` is needed before it.

(you must ALWAYS ***validate*** the `scanf` return before you consider your input valid)

`&temp->data` creates a *pointer-to-pointer-to* `int` (e.g. the address of the pointer to `data`). Printing pointer values with `%x` leads to undefined behavior unless `sizeof (a_pointer)` and `sizeof (unsigned)` are the same on your system (not for x86_64). Use `%p` to print addresses.

Address those issues and let me know if you have further problems.